# describe.each for asynchronous collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I need to make tests for sync collection

Try it:

```
let collection = [];
beforeAll( async() => {  collection = await getAsyncCollection() }

describe.each(collection)("Test summary for collection", (item)=>{
     // ...  .each work with empty collection before than finish "befoerAll", which getting this collection, why?
    })
```

How do it right? And why each working before "beforeAll" ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

## ***Jest execution order***

Jest has its own execution order that can be found [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#order-of-execution).

In other words, when Jest starts, it checks and executes every describe block and execute the code inside them. During this phase, Jest defines describe blocks **synchronously**.

For example:

```
describe('First describe', () => {
    console.log('First')
    before(async () => {
        // your setup 
        console.log('Third')
    })
    it('First test', () => {
       console.log('Fourth')
    })

    describe('Second describe', () => {
        console.log('Second')
        before(async () => {
            // your setup 
            console.log('Fifth')
        })
        it('Second test', () => {
           console.log('Sixth')
        })
     })
 })
```

This snippet produces this log sequence:

```
// First  <-- This one is printed when Jest starts
// Second <-- This line too
// Third  <-- beforeAll() of first describe (when executing your setup)
// Fourth <-- it of first describe
// Fifth  <-- beforeAll() of second describe
// Sixth  <-- it of second describe
```

As you can see, Jest order is not "*linear*", you can't think as if it were top-down order.

For these reasons, setup and teardown operation must be coded inside `before*` and `after*` blocks. Check [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#repeating-setup) for more informations.

Even in your case where `beforeAll()` is external to describe, Jest execution order is applied in same way as just explained.

## ***.each() and why is a little bit tricky***

I had same problem with `.each()` because I wanted to iterate over a table which was created in a `beforeAll()` and then use it as you did.

The problem of this approach is that you are trying to iterate a table which which is still empty because Jest first executes `describe` blocks and then their `before*` functions.

A very tricky workaround that I found is to create a sort of skeleton of your collection containing mocked objects and use it to *fool* Jest and iterate over this dummy skeleton and than populate for real collection with consistent data to user in your tests.

I know this sound a bit difficult, but there is an example:

```
describe('First describe', () => {
    const dummyCollection = createDummyCollection();
    let realCollection;
    before(async () => {
        realCollection = await getAsyncCollection();
    })

    describe.each(dummyCollection)('Describe each', () => {
        it('test', () => {
           // Use here your realCollection
        })
     })
 })
 
 // dummyCollection & realCollection must have the same structure and length so the magic can happens ....
 // dummyCollection = [{test: 'test'}, {test: 'test'}, .....]
 // realCollection = [{real: 'object'}, {real: 'object'}, .....]
```

In this way, you can create a synchronous dummyCollection and an async realCollection.